# Perl Module::Load - using the "load" function to import all the default functions

Tags: perl

I'm using `Module::Load` to load certain modules at runtime. However, I have to make do with an older version (2013) that does not import the `autoload` function.

Thus, I'm doing something like this:

```
use Module::Load;

if(some condition)
{
  load "Cwd", qw(getcwd abs_path);
}
```

I can now use the `getcwd()` and `abs_path()` functions provided by the `Cwd` module.

This is clearly not practical when I need to load a module that imports a lot of functions. How can I use `load` and still manage to import all the default functions *without* having to quote them all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is usually a better idea to just import what you are actually using.  That said, many modules can be asked for `qw(:DEFAULT)` to explicitly get all the default exports.

Comment: I absolutely agree; however, that is difficult in case of modules like `Win32::Registry`, where a whole lot of functions as well as constants are involved. 

Thank you for suggesting `qw(:DEFAULT)` - that seems to be the best solution for me.